# Display a 2D matrix with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

I was wondering if there is any way to plot an image in `d3.js`. Specifically, I am looking for an equivalent of `matplotlib`'s `imshow` functionality in `d3`.

I am looking for something like this:

```
a = numpy.random.randn(25,25)
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(a)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

[image: Image view a random matrix]

I want to do something like this with d3. I looked around and examples on github page and didn't find anything that I could start off with.

Can I request some help/pointers on how to get going with something like this? Thanks!

Comment: I personally would use a contour generator (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4241134) with a gaussian blur. That being said, this question is unfortunately off topic here at S.O.

Comment: Thanks! This is useful. Wonder why off topic though. In any case, I got what I needed. :)

Comment: It is off topic because you are requesting *"help/pointers on how to get going"*. That's completely off topic here, I'm afraid to say. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic